# respnse.body from the http package not returning the required content

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, http, dart

I am building an app that returns the weather information about a city based on the co-Ordinates given(Latitude and longitude).As soon as i print 'print(respnse.body')I am getting a html code not the required weather information .
Here is my code

Main.dart

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    import 'package:clima/screens/loading_screen.dart';
    
    void main() => runApp(MyApp());
    
    class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return MaterialApp(
          theme: ThemeData.dark(),
          home: LoadingScreen(),
        );
      }
    }

Location_Screen.dart

    import 'package:clima/location.dart';
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    import 'package:geolocator/geolocator.dart';
    import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
    class LoadingScreen extends StatefulWidget {
      @override
      _LoadingScreenState createState() => _LoadingScreenState();
    }
    double MyMarginAsDouble;
    class _LoadingScreenState extends State<LoadingScreen> {
    void initState(){//if i call getlocation inside init maethod it automatically gets the location without the need of a button
      super.initState();
      getLocation();
    }
      Future<void> getLocation()
      {
        location ob= location();
        ob.getCurrentLocation();
      }
    Future<void> getData()
    async {
      var url = Uri.parse('api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=35&lon=139&appid=92e463e61258ef5a8b9a9bd11733b62c');
      var response = await http.get(url);
     //code which tells different thing 200 - success 404-failure
      if(response.statusCode==200)
        {
          String data = response.body;
          print(data);
        }
      else
        {
          print(response.statusCode);
        }
    }
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        getData();
        return Scaffold();
      }
    }
 
Location.dart

import 'package:geolocator/geolocator.dart';

class location{
  double latitude;
  double longitude;
  Future<void> getCurrentLocation()
  async {
      try{
        LocationPermission permission = await Geolocator.requestPermission();
        Position position = await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition(desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.low); //high is battery consuming
        LocationPermission permission1 = await Geolocator.checkPermission();
        latitude=position.latitude;
        longitude=position.longitude;
        print(longitude);
        print(latitude);
      }
      catch(e)
      {
        print(e);
      }
    }

  }
```

This is the output I got

```
<html>
    <head>
        <base href="/">
    </head>
    <body>
        <script src="main.dart.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>

77.5578876
12.9219832
```

I am not able to access the weather data of the city London

Answer (score 1):

*(Would add this as a comment but I don't have enough rep to post comments)*

Looking at your code: Uri.parse takes a scheme, like https:// or http://, so:

```
var url = Uri.parse('http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=35&lon=139&appid=92e463e61258ef5a8b9a9bd11733b62c');
```

Looking at the Url source I don't know what it does without one, but it doesn't appear to thrown an error if there's no scheme. Try adding a scheme (http://) and see if you get the correct resource.